# Javascript filering not working when used with string of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I am trying to filter a JavaScript array (JSON array) with the string array, and set it back in itself.

I  am using this code (Removed JSON.stringiFy from allRecords,it was just to show the records on console)

```
var statusFilters = component.get("v.statusFilters");
    console.log('statusFilters--->'+statusFilters);
    var allRecords = component.get("v.empWrapperList");
    console.log('allRecords--->'+allRecords);
    var filteredRecords = allRecords.filter(rec => rec.Status__c == statusFilters);
    console.log(filteredRecords);
    component.set("v.empWrapperList",filteredRecords);`
```

Here `statusFilter` is a string array and allRecords is an object array.

Here are the logs from console.

statusFilters--->Paid
ClaimsDemo.js:119 allRecords--->

```
[
  {
    "Id": "a1V2x000001K29pEAC",
    "Name": "CL-0000004",
    "Member__c": "0032x000004bgAkAAI",
    "Date_of_Service__c": "2020-06-25",
    "Provider__c": "a112x000003VXGEAA4",
    "Status__c": "Void"
  },
  {
    "Id": "a1V2x000001K14OEAS",
    "Name": "CL-0000003",
    "Member__c": "0032x000004bgAkAAI",
    "Billed__c": 22,
    "Date_of_Service__c": "2015-09-15",
    "Provider__c": "a112x000003VXGEAA4",
    "Status__c": "Denied"
  },
  {
    "Id": "a1V2x000001K14JEAS",
    "Name": "CL-0000002",
    "Member__c": "0032x000004bgAkAAI",
    "Billed__c": 22,
    "Date_of_Service__c": "2019-10-16",
    "Provider__c": "a112x000003VXGEAA4",
    "Status__c": "Rejected"
  },
  {
    "Id": "a1V2x000001K14EEAS",
    "Name": "CL-0000001",
    "Member__c": "0032x000004bgAkAAI",
    "Billed__c": 22,
    "Date_of_Service__c": "2020-06-04",
    "Provider__c": "a112x000003VXGEAA4",
    "Status__c": "Paid"
  }
]
```

Actually it is unable to execute this line

```
var filteredRecords = allRecords.filter(rec => rec.Status__c == statusFilters);
```

Can you please help.

Comment: `allRecords` is a string.  You're calling filter on a string... ?

Comment: filter method is for an array not for string

Comment: actually initially I didn;t had that JSON.stringify, I kept it only for console purpose. It still does not work.

Comment: You should be getting an error in your console. It is much easier to help if you [edit] your question to include the full text of the error. Also, JSON is a text format; that's why `JSON.stringify` produces a string. There's no such thing as a JSON Array.

Comment: what is component.get() is it observable or not ?

Comment: @HereticMonkey JSON arrays are a thing. They are just, as all of the JSON, just a string, and not the same as a real Javascript array, which indeed may be a source of confusion for OP.

Comment: @Pac0 No, JSON arrays are not a thing, and saying they are just confuses beginners and makes these kinds of conversations more difficult than they need to be. If you want to talk about how arrays are serialized in the JSON format, talk about that.

Comment: Yeah removed, JSON.stringify, and used the below code in the answer. isArray came as  true..but filteredRecords log has no elements in the array.

Comment: @HereticMonkey the ECMA standard for JSON explicitly mentions arrays as a thing: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf

Comment: I think that is the problem. If you look at the example, there are no `"` wrapping the objects or the outer array container.

Comment: @Pac0 Yes, they mention how arrays are to be serialized in JSON, of course. They also mention how numbers are to be serialized; are we to talk about JSON numbers too?

Comment: @mvk1991 Please, [edit] your question to remove the `JSON.stringify(...)` or you will continually get comments and answers talking about it and it will distract from any other problems you're having.

Comment: Done, btw allRecords is JSON Object Array, and I  get isArray=true

Comment: @HereticMonkey This document is not about serialization from any other language (JS or whatever), it's a standalone document about pure JSON definitions, independent from any other language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your first problem is `stringifying`.`filter` method is for array.

second problem is that you cant say `rec.Status__c === statusFilters` `statusFilters`is array and `Status__c` is string. map to array your object array with correct key name and search `rec.Status__c` in this array. `indexOf` is a method to find in array

if statusFilters is just array which includes types like

```
["Void","Denied"]
```

then

```
var filteredRecords = allRecords.filter(rec => statusFilters.indexOf(rec.Status__c)>-1);
```

if statusFilters  is an object array like

```
[ {"Status__c": "Void" }];
```

then

```
var filteredRecords = allRecords.filter(rec => ( statusFilters.map(x=>x.Status__c)).indexOf(rec.Status__c)>-1);
```

Comment: This broke, this line didn't execute.